# jsp file upload location

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets

hi i am uploading my images using the

```
String filePath = context.getRealPath("/")+"/Library/";
```

all of the images are get to saved in

```
.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyProj/Library/
```

when i list the files in

```
.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyProj/Library/
```

from terminal i can see the images that were uploaded. but if i list the files in

```
.../workspace/MyProj/Library/
```

i cannot see them. also  from eclipse (inside project explorer)

```
MyProj
->Library
```

i cannot see the images uploaded. then i thought probably that location is kind of temp location, and restarted my computer. but uploaded images are still in

```
.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyProj/Library/
```

but through eclipse they are not visible, doing file->refresh also did not help. my questions are follows will the uploaded images stay in this location

```
.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/MyProj/Library/
```

and why i cannot see them from eclipse? if it is possible can you show me how to save them directly in

```
.../workspace/MyProj/Library/
```

thanks!

Comment: What does this have to do with Java, JSPs or servlets? It looks like an Eclipse usage problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the images because eclipse has deployed your webapp to a server and your images are being uploaded to the server.

You can save them directly to your workspace by using:

```
System.getEnv("user.home")+"/workspace/MyProj/Library/"
```

instead of:

```
context.getRealPath("/")+"/Library/";
```